# Thread.Join() not working in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, join

I have a CPTproject class and a CPT class. (CPT is a test; doing which I get a lot of data). I want to read the CPT data from excel files. But since they are large files, I am creating workingThreads to read them conconcerruntly. I want to make sure before I leave the ObtainCPTs() all the workingThreads have returned, that is why I'm calling Join() on them. But still sometimes not all the workingThreads are returning (i.e., the 'Not all CPTs obtained!') message is shown. Can anybody give some hint on what might be the problem?

```
    public static void ObtainCPTs(List<string> fileNames)
    {
        CPTproject.numCPTs = fileNames.Count;

        List<Thread> workingThreads = new List<Thread>() ; 

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Count(); i++)
        {
            HelperClass hp = new HelperClass(fileNames[i]); 

            workingThreads.Add(new Thread(hp.GetCPTdataFromExcel)); 
            workingThreads[i].Start();       
        }

        foreach (Thread t in workingThreads)
        {
            t.Join(); 
        }

        if (CPTproject.CPTs.Count() < CPTproject.numCPTs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not all CPTs obtained!"); 
        }

    }


    class HelperClass
    {
       private string _fileName;

       public helperClass(string fileName)
       {
          this._fileName = fileName;
       }

       public void GetCPTdataFromExcel()
       {
          CPT cpt = new CPT();

          //Reads from excel file with address this._fileName

          CPTproject.CPTs.Add(cpt);
       }
    }
```

Comment: You should use tasks for this :)

Answer (score 2):

If `CPTproject.CPTs` is not a thread-safe collection, then the `Add` method is not thread-safe. You should try putting a `lock` around it

```
class HelperClass
{
   private object _locker = new object();

   public void GetCPTdataFromExcel()
   {
      CPT cpt = new CPT();

      //Reads from excel file with address this._fileName
      lock (_locker) {
          CPTproject.CPTs.Add(cpt);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is a collection. In that case, you can cast to (ICollection) and use the SyncRoot directly instead of adding another object. `lock(((ICollection)CPTproject.SPTs).SyncRoot) { }`

Comment: @ErikNoren actually that is not nessesarly a good idea. Some collections will throw a `NotImplmentedException` if you do that.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Framework ones? I've not checked them all but I know List<> does for sure. The code around the syncroot object seemed written in a way to ensure the object reference never changes during the life of the list. Plus one less single-use object instance floating around your code. I guess you can't expect 3rd party code to be a good citizen.

Comment: I have tried putting the lock around the CPTproject.CPTs.Add(cpt) as John suggested; but still getting the same error! However, the lock(((ICollection)CPTproject.SPTs).SyncRoot) { } is working fine. I'm  wondering why the simple lock is not working! Anyway, thanks guys.

Comment: @ErikNoren Some [base classes](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Abstractions/HttpSessionStateBase.cs#707ceebc8f2ff532) leave it as virtual member with the body set to be NotImplmented, however their derived counterparts [do override them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16977442/80274), but like you said if you are working with 3rd party code that derives a class and does not override the virtual member you could get the error.